# from where does public static void main gets called?

Tags: java

I was just wondering from where actually our main method gets called.
As in eclipse when we run it as an application it automatically gets called. But if i write another method with same signature but different name it doesn't get called

Comment: It is likely invoked from somewhere native: See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is specified in [The java Language Specification, 12.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1):

"The Java Virtual Machine starts execution by invoking the method main of some specified class, passing it a single argument, which is an array of strings"

Answer (score 7):

From the documentation of the `Java Virtual Machine`:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> The java tool launches a Java application. It does this by starting a
>   Java runtime environment, loading a specified class, and invoking that
>   class's main method. The method declaration must look like the
>   following:
>
> **public static void main(String args[])**
>
> The method must be declared
>   public and static, it must not return any value, and it must accept a
>   String array as a parameter. By default, the first non-option argument
>   is the name of the class to be invoked. A fully-qualified class name
>   should be used. If the -jar option is specified, the first non-option
>   argument is the name of a JAR archive containing class and resource
>   files for the application, with the startup class indicated by the
>   Main-Class manifest header.
>
> The Java runtime searches for the startup class, and other classes
>   used, in three sets of locations: the bootstrap class path, the
>   installed extensions, and the user class path.
>
> Non-option arguments after the class name or JAR file name are passed
>   to the main function.
>
> The javaw command is identical to java, except that with javaw there
>   is no associated console window. Use javaw when you don't want a
>   command prompt window to appear. The javaw launcher will, however,
>   display a dialog box with error information if a launch fails for some
>   reason.

Answer (score 1):

It is invoked automatically by the JVM, as specified by the [JVMS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.2) (§5.2. Java Virtual Machine Startup):

> The Java Virtual Machine starts up by creating an initial class, which is specified in an implementation-dependent manner, using the bootstrap class loader (§5.3.1). The Java Virtual Machine then links the initial class, initializes it, **and invokes the public class method `void main(String[])`.**

Thus, `main()` is special. A different method with the same signature but different name won't automatically get called by the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

main method  the entry point for the program. It is called once by the JVM when the program starts.

Answer (score 0):

For *.jar-files you set main class (i.e. class, whose `main()` is to be called) by providing `Main-Class: classname` in `manifest`. In command line invocation you just do `java Main_class_name`. You can set these up in your IDE of choice (in IntelliJ Idea it's, for example, *Main class* entry in *'Edit configurations'* in *Run* menu. In Eclipse or NetBeans, I guess, something similar.

Answer (score 0):

when you execute a java class
step 1 : class file is loaded in to JVM

step 2 : JVM read the bytecode

step 3 : JVM searches all the keywords

step 4 : JVM search for static blocks

step 5 : JVM searches for asynchronous blocks

step 6 : JVM creates a HASH MAP with key being the priorities

step 7 : according to priority JVM executes static blocks from top to bottom , asysnchronous blocks from top to bottom

step 8 : after this JVM searches for the method with the declaration

```
public static void main (String args[])
```

and executes it

so to answer your question  , when a class is being executed JVM calls the main method